# communication between PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I want to send some data to Javascript from PHP.(these two file is different file in same folder)
For example, If I calculate some value in PHP side, I want to send the data to javascript and I use the data.
How can I do this??

Answer (score 6):

There's complete technology for that called [`AJAX`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) with a lot of [tutorials on the internet](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).

And there's already a great and easy-to-deploy implementation - [within `jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 4):

In practice, you can use this:

FILE: index.php

```
<HTML>
    <body>      
        <input type="text" id="test" value="123"><br>
        <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="send_to_php()" value="send to php">

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>

                function send_to_php() {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'js_php.php',
                            type: 'POST',               
                            // Form data
                            data: function(){
                                var data = new FormData();
                                data.append('test', $("#test").val() );     
                                return data;
                            }(),
                            success: function (data) {
                                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                                $("#test").val( obj.result );                   
                            },
                            error: function (data) {
                                console.log(data);
                            },
                            complete: function () {                 

                            },
                            cache: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false
                        });
                }

        </script>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

FILE: js_php.php

```
<?php
    //FILE: js_php.php

    $test = $_POST["test"];
    $test .= "456";

    $arrResult = array(     
        'result' => $test
    );          

    print json_encode($arrResult);
    die();
?>
```

The file "index.php" is the communication between JavaScript and PHP using jQuery Ajax method.
When click the "send to php" button will run the "send_to_php ()" that will take the value of the input id "test" and send through ajax, for "js_php.php" file.
In turn, the file "js_php.php" will receive this variable as POST, modify and print the value in JSON format.
The method implemented by ajax function "send_to_php ()" will be "listening" all that "js_php.php" print.

After the success of the return, javascript convert the text "js_php.php" printed on a JSON object and then the JS able to process within the javascript code:

```
success: function (data) {
    var obj = JSON.parse (data);
    $("# test").val(obj.result);
},
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var myVar = <?php echo $myVar; ?>;
</script>
```

in a nutshell. There are more sophisticated way to communicates though.

Answer (score 2):

Have a Look at this AJAX Tutorial: http://news.php.net/php.general/219164

Answer (score 1):

Assign a JavaScript global variable in a script tag in the PHP page, and include the other javascript files after.

Sample:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>var testGlobal = <?php echo $globalJSValue ?></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="url"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src ="url"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

testGlobal variable will now be available to both javascript files.